# How do I activate Windows 10's built-in unzip feature?

Tags: windows-10, zip

When I right click a video file that has .rar files in Explorer, I don't see the *`Extract All`* option as stated by many online articles.

This is a brand new laptop, so am I supposed to download a secondary Zip program to get Windows 10's working?

Comment: The built-in zip feature has never supported .rar files only .zip

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While you can open .**zip** files automatically you can't do the same with **.rar** files natively within Windows 10.

You need a third-party program like the free [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) software.

Comment: Note that you do not need to install 7-Zip if you use the [Portable Apps](http://portableapps.com/) version.